# Download Insight objecting to security risk with my setup.exe file

Tags: security, installation, symantec

I extract my project setup file with setup factory. But Windows Internet Explorer and Symantec Endpoint Protection acts like it is a harmful application. What can I do to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sign the file with an [Authenticode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) code signing signature.

If you don't sign your executable files, you will have to deal with the user seeing various warning.

Comodo code signing certificates aren't too expensive.

Comment: can i use my site's ssl certificate for sign my exe file? Both of ssl certificate.

Comment: @SavasAdar, no. Unfortunately, that's a different kind of certificate. You have to buy this one separately, but see if your SSL provider also provides code signing certificates to see if you can get a package deal.

Comment: I bought a code sign certificate and i signed my exe with it. But still i get this error. Why? If code certificate doesnt eliminate this, What is a certificate??

Comment: You will have to contact Symantec then. If your file is not malicious, they will have to add an exclusion to their program or tell you how to prevent it.